# Mac not rendering CSS

Tags: macos, firefox

I am a Ubuntu/Windows user and have little experience with Macs.

I made some HTML with inline CSS. However none of the CSS renders in Firefox on the Mac. I tried it as an external CSS file, but it doesn't work either on the Mac.

The same HTML/CSS works on Windows.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Are you developing your own website? Is this local to your machine or actually on a web server somewhere? We need more information than this to be able to answer or direct your question to the correct site where it can be answered.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Macs come with Safari installed, but Firefox and Chrome are also available. I do web development everyday on my mac and have not had problems. Which browser are you using on Windows? Does thsi html/css work on Firefox in Ubuntu?

Comment: The issue would be probably easy to solve if you provide the browser used in this case that nothing is rendered(firefox, ie5, Safari?), and its version(ie, Firefox 3.6 ), and really important, the url of the site that has the problem, or if not, at least paste here the code, which is behaving like that.  :) (edit: sorry, repeated the browser question)

Comment: Please specify your browser version(s), OS version, and show us the HTML/CSS you use, both versions, inline CSS and separate files.

Answer (score 0):

You should validate your HTML and CSS using the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/) get it clean and then see if Safari on Mac can render it.

Check that the browser isn't replaying a cached copy of an older version of your page. In the worst case you may have to close and re-load the browser. Some browsers let you override the local cache by forcing a reload using a key combination such as Ctrl+F5. There may be something similar for Safari on Mac.

Use "View Source" to check that the browser is receiving the latest version of your page. You can explicitly fetch external CSS to see if your browser is fetching the latest version of the CSS.

Comment: Doesn't refresh work on Mac?

Comment: @shinokada:Very possibly, I don't have a Mac. What's more important than platform is which browser you are using. I guess most Mac users use Safari - are you?